# what is timeout interval for cancel download after wifi disconnect

Tags: timeout, download, wifi, disconnect

in android , what is time out interval for cancel download after WiFi disconnect -
If user start download a file 100 MB , and if his WiFi is disconnect , after some time download is cancelled , and if after some time he get WiFi connectivity then system automatically start remaining download ,so I want information about time interval for cancel download after WiFi disconnect ,and who set this time interval (it is set by application or it is set by android system) ?? please help me .